# Procedure or function checkLogin11 has too many arguments specified exception

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Although this stored procedure works for first time( for first login) and after logout or after re-run application, this stored procedure not work and throws "Procedure or function checkLogin11 has too many arguments specified exception". I only supply required parameters and it work fine for first time and then it does not . Can't understand whats wrong. Please suggest me what to do.

stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkLogin11
@userName nvarchar(50) = null,
@userPassword nvarchar(50) = null,
@userType nvarchar(50) = null
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT lu.LoginID  FROM arstbl_LoginUser as lu WHERE lu.UserName = @userName AND lu.Password = @userPassword AND lu.Type = @userType
END
GO
```

code:

```
scmd.Connection = scon;
scmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
scmd.CommandText = "checkLogin11";
scmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userName;
scmd.Parameters.Add("@userPassword", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = password;
scmd.Parameters.Add("@userType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userType;

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

try
  {
     scon.Open();
     sda.Fill(dt);

     if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        return true;
     else
     return false;
  }

finally
  {
     scon.Close();
  }
```

It throws exception while filling datatable.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have used the same **command** object(scmd) in some other function or there might be possible chance of event bubbling.try clearing the parameter before you execute the statement(scmd.Parameters.Clear())

```
scmd.Connection = scon;
scmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
scmd.CommandText = "checkLogin11";

**scmd.Parameters.Clear();**

scmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userName;
scmd.Parameters.Add("@userPassword", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = password;
scmd.Parameters.Add("@userType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userType;

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

try
  {
     scon.Open();
     sda.Fill(dt);

     if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        return true;
     else
     return false;
  }

finally
  {
     scon.Close();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you . it works fine after adding scmd.parameter.clear();